# Problem using numba-scipy for special functions

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numba

I would like to make numba compatible with the scipy special function error function "scipy.special.erf", as I use this function in a finite difference scheme which I believe could be sped up by using numba.

To do so, I installed numba-scipy 0.3.0 using [conda](https://anaconda.org/numba/numba-scipy), which [should support the special function error function](https://numba-scipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/special.html).

I then built a very minimal example to see if I could get numba to run with a function calling scipy.special.erf. The code is the following:

```
from numba import jit
import scipy.special as sc

@jit
def f(x, y, N):
    for i in range(N):
        x +=sc.erf(y)
    return x


print(f(1,1,1))
```

I get the error message copied at the end of this question. One issue is clearly linked to the error function call it seems, but I'm a bit at a loss on what is going wrong exactly and how to fix it. Any help on this issue is most welcome.

Error message reads:

```
test.py:4: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "f" failed type inference due to: No implementation of function Function(<ufunc 'erf'>) found for signature:
 
 >>> erf(int64)
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Overload of function 'erf': File: numba_scipy/special/overloads.py: Line 9.
    With argument(s): '(int64)':
   No match.

During: resolving callee type: Function(<ufunc 'erf'>)
During: typing of call at test.py (7)


File "test.py", line 7:
def f(x, y, N):
    <source elided>
    for i in range(N):
        x +=sc.erf(y)
        ^

  @jit
test.py:4: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITHOUT looplifting enabled because Function "f" failed type inference due to: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numba.core.dispatcher.LiftedLoop'>

File "test.py", line 6:
def f(x, y, N):
    for i in range(N):
    ^

  @jit
/Users/*************/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/object_mode_passes.py:177: NumbaWarning: Function "f" was compiled in object mode without forceobj=True, but has lifted loops.

File "test.py", line 6:
def f(x, y, N):
    for i in range(N):
    ^

  warnings.warn(errors.NumbaWarning(warn_msg,
/Users/******************/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/object_mode_passes.py:187: NumbaDeprecationWarning: 
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.

For more information visit https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit

File "test.py", line 6:
def f(x, y, N):
    for i in range(N):
    ^

  warnings.warn(errors.NumbaDeprecationWarning(msg,
```

Comment: Did you try float argument?

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much, sorry for not having checked that before.

Comment: What is the resolution here? What do you mean "try float argument"? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @ShepBryan "try float argument" meant trying to pass y=1.0 instead of y=1 as the second argument of my test function f. It solved the problem, sc.erf just does not expect/work with an int64 argument, which I was using in my test.

Comment: @FrançoisP I don't see you importing numba-scipy here. How do you incorporate that package in your code? There is no user guide in the docs.